# How to use LIKE operator with multiple conditions at once in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query

I want to select records using LIKE operator with multiple conditions, I can use `OR` between the conditions but I am looking for a short way to solve this issue.
I am trying the following query:

```
select * 
from employees 
where name like '%.%' 
   OR name like '%,%' 
   OR name like '%;%' 
   OR name like '%/%' -- this code goes very long
```

I am looking for a way to shorten this query.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can combine the `LIKE` operator with an array:

```
select * 
from employees 
where name like any (array['%.%', '%,%', %;%', ...]);
```

Or a completely different approach, that does not require to repeat the wildcard for each value:

```
select e.*
from employees e
where exists (select *
              from (values(('.'), (','), (';'))) as t(ch) 
              where e.name like concat('%', t.ch, '%'))
```

---

As you only check for single characters, you could use Postgres' array functions as well: by turning the name into an array of characters and checking for an overlapping array:

```
select * 
from employees 
where string_to_array(name, null) &&  array['.', ',', ';'];
```

or

```
select * 
from employees 
where string_to_array(name, null) &&  string_to_array('.,;', null);
```

Comment: Can you confirm your second example works?  When I try it, it only picks up the first element in the `values()` list, and the remaining elements are ignored.  I can shuffle around the elements in the `values()` list but it only ever matches the first one.